# Appending to an XML file while checking current nodes

Tags: java, xml, append, exists

I have searched everywhere for this issue but can't figure out what's going on.

What I'm trying to do is append something to the end of an XML file while checking the nodes to make sure it does not already have that node in there. So if I wanted to add  into an XML file but  is already there it doesn't write to it.

The issue I'm having is that it appends to the end fine but it does it whether the node exists or not. So if I run this 5 times I end up having it append the same thing five times instead of just once. My code is as below:

```
    public void writeSettingsFile(String file, String keyIn, String contentIn)
{
    try {
        String filepath = file;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        docFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        Node settings = doc.getElementsByTagName("Settings").item(0);

        NodeList list = settings.getChildNodes();

        Element newSetting = doc.createElement(keyIn);
        newSetting.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(contentIn));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

            if (!keyIn.equals(node.getNodeName()) && !hasWhiteSpace(node))
            {
                settings.appendChild(newSetting);
                System.out.println("This should be written");
                System.out.println("Not written");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not written"); 
            }
        }

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured it out, I changed the loop a bit, I created a boolean variable that holds whether key is found. Set to false by default, it scans through the keys and if found it then changed keyFound to true, which will then not write our new key, if it isn't found it will stay as false which will write our key. Code posted below.

```
            Boolean keyFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

            if (keyIn.equals(node.getNodeName()))
            {

                keyFound = true;
                System.out.println("Found");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All keys scanned");
        if (keyFound == false)
        {
            settings.appendChild(newSetting);
            System.out.println("Written");
        }
```